# specific file type attachment in ms access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

Is there any way or control property to bound the specific file type (such as .gif) to an attachment data type field in access-2016 rather than supporting the all supported file formats by access and Is there any way to limit the number of attachments to a single file.

Comment: File attachments and propietary fields are like the dark side Luke... You should not approach them, if possible.

Comment: Actually such type of control is available in one-note. I Thought it may available in access but no luck. I can't bound the data entry operator to upload such type of files. Thanks for your suggestion. @Lybren